# Drupal 7: Adding filters into View programmatically

Tags: drupal, filter, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I created taxonomy view to display content of different Categories, and my client want to have different exposed filters for different categories. For example, Shoes category should have filters Color, Shoe length, Shoelace color, while Clothes category should have filter Material and Color, while Bag should not have any category at all.

Been trying things on my own but nothing works. Searches on Google only found some ways to change an existing filter's value, but not creating a whole new filter and injecting it into the view.

Yolo people, Any suggestions? - and by saying YOLO i meant You Only Live Online

Comment: The answer I posted [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200870/6488) addresses programmatically adding or modifying a filter to a view, I have not tried but one should be able to use something similar for exposed filters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using '[Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)' module together with views API. Which allows you to implement custom filters by extending `views_handler_filter` class.

Comment: Going to try it out and get back to this. Thanks for the suggestion!